# node-sass-chokidar doesn't install on npm install

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, npm, node-sass

I have an react app created using create-react-app.

To compile sass files I'm using node-sass-chokidar as recommended in the [docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc).

It's installing and working fine on my local machine (os x). But when I add it to my production server (Ubuntu 14.04.5 x32 running nginx) and run

```
npm install
```

it's not installing. I can see this by checking the /node_modules folder where it's not showing up ( as it does on my local machine ).

Sass is installed on the server.

When I run npm install I get this error the first time I run it

```
> fsevents@1.0.17 install 
/var/www/bertgenerator.com/html/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp verb cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs',
node-pre-gyp verb cli '/var/www/bertgenerator.com/html/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin 
node-pre-gyp',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   'install',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   '--fallback-to-build' ]
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.32
node-pre-gyp info using node@6.11.0 | linux | ia32
node-pre-gyp verb command install []
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/var/www/bertgenerator.com/html/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-linux-ia32/fse.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.17/fse-v1.0.17-node-v48-linux-ia32.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.17/fse-v1.0.17-node-v48-linux-ia32.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.17/fse-v1.0.17-node-v48-linux-ia32.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.17 and node@6.11.0 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.17/fse-v1.0.17-node-v48-linux-ia32.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp verb command build [ 'rebuild' ]
make: Entering directory `/var/www/bertgenerator.com/html/node_modules/fsevents/build'
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
  COPY Release/.node
make: Leaving directory `/var/www/bertgenerator.com/html/node_modules/fsevents/build'
node-pre-gyp info ok
```

I don't know if it's related. If I run npm install again I don't get the error.

I have tried to remove the /node_modules folder and run

```
npm cache clean
```

as well as

```
sudo npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
npm install chokidar --save
```

this worked for me, when my

```
sudo npm install -g
```

did not install chokidar. More info on npm-chokidar [here](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sudo npm i` ?

That worked for me when nothing else did.

`npm i` silently fails in some cases for some packages requiring administrative privildeges and sudo ensures that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).